# unboundlocalerror message in my code and Im not sure what is wrong

Tags: python

My code is as follows and after I enter in the inputs I receive a "UnboundedLocalError: local variable "bmr" referenced before assignment" error. I have played around with the indentation of the bmr variable but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions are much appreciated

```
def bmr_calc():
  weightKg = int(input("Weight: "))
  heightInc = int(input("Height: "))
  age = int(input("Age: "))
  gender = input("Are you a (m)ale or (f)emale:").lower

  if gender == "m":
    bmr = int((66.47 + (6.24*weightKg) + (12.7*heightInc) - (6.76*age)))
  elif gender == "f":
    bmr = int(((4.54*weightKg) + (15.88*heightInc) - (5*age) - 161))
  print(bmr)
  return bmr

bmr = bmr_calc()
```

Comment: The message should be pretty clear: `bmr` is not set. This happens when someone doesn't enter "m" or "f" for gender.

Comment: I have added in both m and f with the same error coming up

Comment: `.lower` is a method, you need to actually call it rather than access it, i.e. `.lower()`.  Also, try defining the return value `bmr` to some default value would avoid the exception and help you narrow down the actual issue with your code.